Course registrations statistics
I have the following two tables courses and enrollments in my PieCloudDB Database:



course_id
course_name




1
Deep Learning


2
Data Science


3
C++






enrollment_id
course_id
customer_id
enrollment_date




101
1
201
2024-01-15


102
1
202
2024-01-20


103
2
203
2024-02-01


104
3
204
2024-02-15


105
1
205
2024-03-01


106
2
206
2024-03-10


107
3
207
2024-03-20



I now want to query the number of registrations for each course per month and the cumulative number of registrations for the course.
Below is my query:
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.enrollment_date) AS year,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.enrollment_date) AS month,
    c.course_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT e.customer_id) AS monthly_registrations,
    SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT e.customer_id)) OVER (
        PARTITION BY e.course_id
        ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.enrollment_date), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.enrollment_date)
    ) AS cumulative_registrations
FROM
    enrollments e
JOIN
    courses c ON e.course_id = c.course_id
GROUP BY
    e.course_id,
    c.course_name,
    year,
    month
ORDER BY
    year,
    month,
    c.course_name;

Then I got the results:



year
month
course_name
monthly_registrations
cumulative_registrations




2024
1
Deep Learning
2
2


2024
2
C++
1
1


2024
2
Data Science
1
1


2024
3
C++
1
2


2024
3
Data Science
1
2


2024
3
Deep Learning
1
3



Now there is a problem. I want to get more complete information. When the number of registrations for a certain course in a certain month is 0, it also need to be outputted.
For example, for the above data I would like to get a result like this:



year
month
course_name
monthly_registrations
cumulative_registrations




2024
1
C++
0
0


2024
1
Data Science
0
0


2024
1
Deep Learning
2
2


2024
2
C++
1
1


2024
2
Data Science
1
1


2024
2
Deep Learning
0
2


2024
3
C++
1
2


2024
3
Data Science
1
2


2024
3
Deep Learning
1
3



I don't know how to do it, can anyone help me?(If you don't know PieCloudDB, you can use PostgreSQL instead, thanks)

Tested with Postgres on db fiddle, hope it works for your PieCloudDB:
https://dbfiddle.uk/Cl2UgltH
WITH course_list AS (
    SELECT course_id, course_name FROM courses
),
month_list AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM enrollment_date) AS year, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM enrollment_date) AS month
    FROM enrollments
),
all_combinations AS (
    SELECT cl.course_id, cl.course_name, ml.year, ml.month
    FROM course_list cl, month_list ml
)
SELECT
    year,
    month,
    course_name,
    COALESCE(monthly_registrations, 0) AS monthly_registrations,
    SUM(COALESCE(monthly_registrations, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY course_name ORDER BY year, month) AS cumulative_registrations
FROM (
    SELECT
        ac.year,
        ac.month,
        ac.course_name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT e.customer_id) AS monthly_registrations
    FROM all_combinations ac
    LEFT JOIN enrollments e ON ac.year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.enrollment_date)
                            AND ac.month = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.enrollment_date)
                            AND ac.course_id = e.course_id
    GROUP BY ac.year, ac.month, ac.course_name
) sub
ORDER BY year, month, course_name;

